# Playframework parallel rendering

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, loops

I want to process several tasks in parallel inside a Action, and push back any task result in first-completed order and as soon as it completes.

For example, if task A completes in 5 secs, task B completes in 3 secs and task C completes in 1 sec, the output should be "C", "B", "A".

The following codes seems output the wrong order and await all the task completes before output the result.

```
def lookup  = Action { implicit  req =>
    val a = Enumerator( Await.result(Promise.timeout("A", 5 seconds), 1 minute))
    val b = Enumerator( Await.result(Promise.timeout("B", 3 seconds), 1 minute))
    val c = Enumerator( Await.result(Promise.timeout("C", 1 second), 1 minute))

    val d = a >- b >- c

    Ok.chunked(d &> Comet(callback = "console.log"))
}
```

Comment: What is your actual use case?  This code looks pretty contrived, what with an Await.result nested in an Enumerator.

Comment: @Ryan I just wanted to simulate the sources for Enumerator are several blocked functions. It's like `Enumerator(someFunction)`, I thought it was easier to illustrate this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is broken because of how you are using `Await.result`. The line that defines `a` doesn't complete until `Await.result` returns, and so the promise for `b` never starts until after the one for `a` has finished. If you use something like:

```
val a = Enumerator.flatten(Future.firstCompletedOf(List(
  Promise.timeout("A", 5 seconds),
  Promise.timeout(throw new Exception("A timed out"), 1 minute)
)).map(Enumerator(_)))
```

You will get correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks for point out this, so what's the usual pattern for this case - Enumerators need to get sources from different `def taskX:Future[X]`?

Comment: `Enumerator.flatten(future.map(Enumerator(_)))` will convert Futures into Enumerators, they can then be combined with `>-`. Timeouts should really be handled by whatever is producing the future so it can stop what it is doing when the timeout triggers, e.g. see `WSRequestHolder.withRequestTimeout`.